# R: save txt with tab as header of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, export, write.table

I have a very large data frame with SNPs in rows (~50.000) and IDs in columns (~500), imagine an extraction would look something like this:

```
      R015 R016 R007
cg158 0.81 0.90 0.87
cg178 0.91 0.80 0.58
```

Now I want to save this as a txt, normally no problem with
`write.table(example, "example.txt", colnames=T, rownames=T, quotes=F)`
BUT I need to have **a tab (\t) as first column entrance**, so in the txt file the data frame should look sth like:

```
 \t   R015 R016 R007
cg158 0.81 0.90 0.87
cg178 0.91 0.80 0.58
```

(\t for the tab)

Can anyone help me how to do this?
Btw I also tried:
`write.table(data.frame("\t"=rownames(example),example),"example.txt", row.names=FALSE)`
It did not work, unfortunately...

Thanks!

Comment: Can't think of a way to do this with write.table in R. Can you save the file then use sed to replace the first occurrence of R015?, e.g. sed -i 's/R015/    R015/' example.txt

Comment: I think this could be also an option but as the data frame is VERY large I have double processing time then (first extracting the data to txt and then change it again in a new file)... But shouldn't it be sed 's/R015/\tRo15/' example txt > example_new.txt then? To have the \t before the first column? And then I have to extract the table in R with colnames and rownames T, right?

Comment: I think it depends on your system whether you need to add a native tab (not clear in my previous comment) or \t in the command. The -i option is to edit the file in place, so should be quick, see for example https://dwr.io/2012/08/super-fast-find-and-replace-with-sed/

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works, just replace `stdout()` with the path to your output-file:

```r
data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100,3), 
                   y = sample(1:100,3), 
                   z = sample(1:100,3))
row.names(data) <- LETTERS[1:3]
lines <- c(paste(c(' ', names(data)), collapse = '\t'),
           sapply(seq_len(nrow(data)),
       function(i){
         paste(c(row.names(data)[i], data[i,]),collapse = '\t')
       }))
writeLines(lines, con = stdout())
#>      x   y   z
#> A    35  97  27
#> B    12  69  24
#> C    25  9   34
```

Or with spaces as seperators and the tab you wished for in the first column:

```r
data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100,3), 
                   y = sample(1:100,3), 
                   z = sample(1:100,3))
row.names(data) <- LETTERS[1:3]
lines <- c(paste(c('\t', names(data)), collapse = ' '),
           sapply(seq_len(nrow(data)),
       function(i){
         paste(c(row.names(data)[i], data[i,]),collapse = ' ')
       }))
writeLines(lines, con = stdout())
#>   x y z
#> A 3 30 11
#> B 62 69 70
#> C 93 55 73
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean to replace stdout or write the path in the brackets? The folder I am in is the same folder where I want to save my output to. So should I end with: writeLines(lines, con=stdout(example.txt)) or writeLines(lines, con=example.txt)?

Comment: The second one, just remember to use quotation marks.

Comment: Now I figured out that with your example this works fine, but when I use another data frame (eg. just the example df from gersht) R prints the txt without column headers at all... This is very strange. I do not know what the problem is, but I tried it several times with 2 different data frames and it still remains.

Comment: I tried it with `iris` and gersht's df and didn't have any problems. I successfully ran this code:
`data = read.table(text = "R015 R016 R007
cg158 0.81 0.90 0.87
cg178 0.91 0.80 0.58")
lines <- c(paste(c(' ', names(data)), collapse = '\t'),
 sapply(seq_len(nrow(data)),
        function(i){
          paste(c(row.names(data)[i], data[i,]),collapse = '\t')
        }))
 writeLines(lines, con = 'test.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

Using a data frame like the following, where I've changed one row name to illustrate how to deal with cases of unequal length:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "R015 R016 R007
cg158 0.81 0.90 0.87
cg178kdfj 0.91 0.80 0.58")
```

You could do something like this:

```r
df <- format(as.matrix(df))
df <- cbind("\\t" = rownames(df), df)
df <- rbind(colnames(df), df)
df[,1] <- stringr::str_pad(df[,1], max(nchar(df[,1])), "right")
write.table(df,
            file = "example.txt",
            sep = " ",
            quote = F,
            row.names = F,
            col.names = F)
```

Output:

```
\t        R015 R016 R007
cg158     0.81 0.90 0.87
cg178kdfj 0.91 0.80 0.58
```

I first converted the numeric values to character and `format`ted them to make sure they have the same number of digits, otherwise they won't line up. Then I turn the row names into a new variable named `\\t`, and then I turn the column names into a new row. I use `stringr::str_pad()` to account for row names of differing lengths. Finally, I write the data frame to TXT file without the row or column names.

Comment: Ok in this case this seems to work fine, however I do not understand where you formatted them to have the same digits.. And as far as I understood this can become problematic with rownames of different lenght and numbers of different length?

Comment: @LotteLi my call to `format` formats the digits. There shouldn't be any issue with numbers with different length - `format` takes care of that. Varying length row names will be a problem regardless of the solution you use. You'll need pad the strings with empty space, either by using something like base R's `formatC()` or `stringr::str_pad()`. The second option is a little easier in my experience.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to do this here with this Code? Assuming the row names differ in length... I do not really know how I could embedd it in the code...

Comment: Additionally I now saw that the colnames are:
\t \tR015 \tR016 ...
This is a problem because I need \t R015 \tR016 \tR007...
So there should not be 2 \t at the beginning! Do you have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: @LotteLi removing only the second tab doesn't make sense because it's a delimiter – it would completely throw off the alignment. What might make more sense is to use a different delimiter.  I've updated the answer with a strategy that produces a result more closely resembling your example output. Instead of `\t` I use a space `" "` as the delimiter.